# R extract first number from string

Tags: regex, r, gsub, strsplit

I have a string in a variable which we call v1. This string states picture numbers and takes the form of "Pic 27 + 28". I want to extract the first number and store it in a new variable called item.

Some code that I've tried is:

```
item <- unique(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(v1),"[^0-9]+")))))
```

This worked fine, until I came upon a list that went:

```
[1,] "Pic 26 + 25"
[2,] "Pic 27 + 28"
[3,] "Pic 28 + 27"
[4,] "Pic 29 + 30"
[5,] "Pic 30 + 29"
[6,] "Pic 31 + 32"
```

At this point I get more numbers than I want, as it is also grabbing other unique numbers (the 25).

I've actually tried doing it with gsub, but got nothing to work. Help would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: Would there ever be 100+ pictures.  For example, would it ever be "Pic 105 + 104" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume that you'd like to extract the first of two numbers in each string.

You may use the `stri_extract_first_regex` function from the [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(c("Pic 26+25", "Pic 1,2,3", "no pics"), "[0-9]+")
## [1] "26" "1"  NA
```

Answer (score 6):

In the responses below we use this test data:

```
# test data
v1 <- c("Pic 26 + 25", "Pic 27 + 28", "Pic 28 + 27", "Pic 29 + 30", 
"Pic 30 + 29", "Pic 31 + 32")
```

**1) gsubfn**

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(v1, "(\\d+).*", as.numeric, simplify = c)
## [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

**2) sub**  This requires no packages but does involve a slightly longer regular expression:

```
as.numeric( sub("\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", v1) )
## [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

**3) read.table**  This involves no regular expressions or packages:

```
read.table(text = v1, fill = TRUE)[[2]]
## [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

In this particular example the `fill=TRUE` could be omitted but it might be needed if the     components of `v1` had a differing number of fields.

Answer (score 5):

With `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

vec = c("Pic 26 + 25", "Pic 27 + 28", "Pic 28 + 27", 
        "Pic 29 + 30", "Pic 30 + 29", "Pic 31 + 32")

str_extract(v1, "[0-9]+")
# [1] "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this very nicely with the `str_first_number()` function from the `strex` package, or for more general needs, you can use the `str_nth_number()` function. Install it with `install.packages("strex")`.

```
library(strex)
#> Loading required package: stringr
strings <- c("Pic 26 + 25", "Pic 27 + 28", "Pic 28 + 27",
             "Pic 29 + 30", "Pic 30 + 29", "Pic 31 + 32")
str_first_number(strings)
#> [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31
str_nth_number(strings, n = 1)
#> [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow up your `strsplit` attempt:

```
# split the strings
l <- strsplit(x = c("Pic 26 + 25", "Pic 27 + 28"), split = " ")
l
# [[1]]
# [1] "Pic" "26"  "+"   "25" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Pic" "27"  "+"   "28" 

# extract relevant part from each list element and convert to numeric
as.numeric(lapply(l , `[`, 2))
# [1] 26 27
```